# Cant find a difference between VPAID 1 vs VPAID2

Tags: video, ads, vast

How can I tell the difference between VPAID 1.0/2.0?
All major AdCompanies switch to VPAID 2 with VAST 3.0. How can one tell whether its Vpaid 1 or Vpaid 2?

Answer (score 2):

"VPAID 2.0" is used ambigously: it can either refer to the interface and handshake between creative and player or it can be used to differentiate VPAID that can run in HTML5 players.

Flash VPAID usually communicates with the player via interface definition 1.1.0 or 2.0 (version 1.0 is deprecated); one of the few test pages giving away the handshake is http://tagvalidator.videohub.tv

VPAID is not restricted to flash and can run with HTML5 players as well, but of course such VPAID must be written in Javascript rather than Flash's ActionScript. Since VPAID for HTML5 environments has been developed later than VPAID for flash, the term VPAID 2 is sometimes being used, but it is more clear to explicitly refer to "HTML5 VPAID" or "VPAID JS".

Answer (score 0):

Once the ad has loaded, the player will call handshakeVersion() on the ad and pass the VPAID version is supports to the ad. The ad will respond to the call by returning the highest VPAID version it supports.

> The video player calls handshakeVersion immediately after loading the ad unit to indicate to
>   the ad unit that VPAID will be used. The video player passes in its latest VPAID version string.
>   The ad unit returns a version string minimally set to “1.0”, and of the form “major.minor.patch”
>   (i.e. “2.1.05”). The video player must verify that it supports the particular version of VPAID or
>   cancel the ad.